# Get count of unique values of properties from JSON API response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, angularjs

I have a JSON API served by a Ruby on Rails backend. One of the endpoints returns an array of objects structured like this

```
{
  "title_slug": "16-gaijin-games-bittrip-beat-linux-tar-gz",
  "platform": "Linux",
  "format": ".tar.gz",
  "title": "BIT.TRIP BEAT",
  "bundle": "Humble Bundle for Android 3",
  "unique_games": 9
},
{
  "title_slug": "17-gaijin-games-bittrip-beat-linux-deb",
  "platform": "Linux",
  "format": ".deb",
  "title": "BIT.TRIP BEAT",
  "bundle": "Humble Bundle for Android 3",
  "unique_games": 9
},
```

Because there are different types of downloads for a single title the "Title" is not unique across several objects. I would like a count of only unique titles.

I was thinking of doing it in Ruby on Rails in the model and just sending it in the JSON response but that does not work because it needs the whole array to count them, obviously. I am using angular on the front end so I am thinking it needs to be done in the controller. I also filter the response in a table and want updated numbers of the unique titles being displayed.

Here's a screenshot of the page this is going on to get better perspective. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFx3L.png

Thank you very much,

Thomas Le

BTW, this is a site I am developing that is not going to be a public website. It is a database site that holds all the data on the bundles I have bought from `IndieGala` and `HumbleBundle`. I am not going to make these links available to the public. I am making it more functional than the bare minimum because it is an open source project that I have on GitHub that people can use themselves locally.

Just in case people were wondering why I have Humble Bundle stuff listed on the image.

Comment: Counting is trivial -> **http://jsfiddle.net/215znzwt/**, as for how to implement it, that's something I think you'll have to figure out on your own ?

Comment: I knew it was easy, but for some reason I couldn't think of how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hy7rasp4/

Aggregate your data in an array indexed by the unique key, Then you get access to information on duplicates and count.

```
var i,
    title,
    uniqueResults= {};

for (i in results) {
   title= results[i].title;
   if (!uniqueResults[title]) {
      uniqueResults[title]= [];
   }

   uniqueResults[title].push(results[i]);
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are almost identical but I ended up using this one so I am marking this one as the chosen answer. I added a count inside the if statement to get the count of unique names. I tried doing a `uniqueResults.length` and `.count` but it didn't work the way I thought it would.

Comment: @thomasle this is because uniqueResults is an object and not an array. To get the number of keys in an object you can try using Object.keys(uniqueResults).length. Be careful though if you wish to support all browsers as this method is not guaranteed to work on all browsers. You can find more details here         https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: thank you. I am not worried about cross compatibility because it is a local site and I use chrome just about exclusively :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to restructure your data at the same time, so you can also get those items easily later as well as a quick lookup for the number of titles, e.g. in *JavaScript*

```js
// assuming arrayOfObjects

var objectOfTitles = {},
    i;
for (i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; ++i) {
    if (!objectOfTitles.hasOwnProperty(arrayOfObjects[i].title)) {
        objectOfTitles[arrayOfObjects[i].title] = [];
    }
    objectOfTitles[arrayOfObjects[i].title].push(arrayOfObjects[i]);
}

var numberOfTitles = Object.keys(objectOfTitles).length;
// then say you choose a title you want, and you can do
// objectOfTitles[chosenTitle] to get entries with just that title
```